# Contradiction in microsoft pattern approach with GC?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I know that the role of dispose function is to clear the unmanaged resources.

but according to [Microsoft's pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)   ( which I understand ) they  doing that :

They  opened a new centralized function which takes a `bool` ( isDispoisng) ;

if `True` , so  it came from dispose func ( using `using` or something else) - and it clears the unmanaged **and managed**

if `false` , it came from finalizer / destructor. and he kills just the unmanaged.

I dont understand why microsoft's pattern kills  also the `managed` if `isDispoisng==True` ( see the bolded words).

I *thought* the finilize should kill *just* the unmanaged....

Can you please explain ?

What did they want to achieve in this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your managed resources may hold on to other (unmanaged) resources that may need to be disposed of.

Any object that implements IDisposable should therefore be disposed by calling its Dispose method.

Edit: And indeed, event handler hookups also need to be eliminated that would otherwise prevent an object from going out of scope and being garbage collected.

Comment: Also, some managed objects can have event hooks that are not released until its disposed. These events can keep the object reachable and thus alive preventing the finalizer from running.

Comment: @Peladao So the CLASS's dispose will free also managed objects which holds references to OTHER unmanaged resources ? I guess were talking about  the finilize of `this`  class and not other classes... so....`my dispose function is releasing MY unmanaged objects and also MY managed objects which may/not have other references to unmanaged objects `...correct ?

Comment: Yes, a Dispose implementation should release any unmanaged objects and event handlers and call Dispose on any (managed) objects it owns so that they can (recursively) do the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a performance and latency cost involved in finalization.  Ideally, we should be attempting to avoid invocation of the finalizer should be avoided for any given instance.  This is possible if Dispose is invoked and it cleans up the unmanaged resources.

If you're interested in a somewhat clearer explanation of the recommended disposition pattern than what you will find in most MSDN content, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx is a pretty good place to start.

Incidentally, implementation of a finalizer is no longer the recommended approach for cleanup of unmanaged resources as of .NET 2.0.  Instead, you should be using a [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) except in a [very few "special" scenarios](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=86c71425-57bc-4fcb-b34b-3262812f12cf).